# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TouchPoints'

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

How to fix this. Error message: The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TouchPoints'.

[image]

This is My code. Error message: The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TouchPoints'.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    points.add(TouchPoints(
        points: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
        paint: Paint()
          ..strokeCap = strokeType
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
    points.add(TouchPoints(
        points: Offset(616.0, 0.0),
        paint: Paint()
          ..strokeCap = strokeType
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
    points.add(TouchPoints(
        points: Offset(616.0, 616),
        paint: Paint()
          ..strokeCap = strokeType
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
    points.add(TouchPoints(
        points: Offset(0.0, 616),
        paint: Paint()
          ..strokeCap = strokeType
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth)); 
    points.add(TouchPoints(
        points: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
        paint: Paint()
          ..strokeCap = strokeType
          ..isAntiAlias = true
          ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));    
    points.add(null); //ERROR
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: what is `points` variable in this case?

Comment: List<TouchPoints> points = []; Point is a list

Comment: Can you help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`List<TouchPoints> points = [];` does not accept null value.

We can only add non-null value `TouchPoints`. TO accepts null value, you can create list like bellow to accept null value.

```dart
List<TouchPoints?> points = [];
```

You can avoid adding null value if it is not necessary and keep the list declaration as it is.

I will encourage you to check [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: I agree with Yeasin's answer!

Comment: I got a new error. pointsList: points, . points is error

Comment: Can I change the //points.add(null) code like this?

Comment: yes you can comment or remove `//points.add(null)`. if you make inner list nullable, you need to check null whenever using list item.

Answer (score 0):

In null-safety you can't add null value to the list such this case. But you can make the list to accept null values by adding '?' operator after the data type to become as follows:

```
List<TouchPoints?> points = [];
```

Comment: ? adds undefined value, not null value